# jQuery AJAX .each() not stopping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Not sure if the title makes sense but here's my problem;

I currently use Dropbox to share family photos, trying to put them all into an HTML page in their own DIV based on their content.

I load them via a JSON file that looks like this

```
[
    {
        "Birthday": "10"
    },
    {
        "Camping": "20"
    },
    {
        "July Fourth": "50"
    }
]
```

And using jQuery .ajax to load them

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'events.json',
    success: function(response) {
      $.each(response, function() {
        $.each(this, function(name, photos) {
          $('#container').append('<div class="gallery" name="' + name + '"></div>');
          $('div[name="' + name + '"').append(function() {
            for ( var i = 1; i <= photos; i++) {
              if (i < 10) {
                $('.gallery').append('<a class="fancybox" rel="' + this + '" href="' + name + '/0' + i + '.jpg"><img class="img" src="' + name + '/0' + i + '.jpg" /></a>');
              } else {
                $('.gallery').append('<a class="fancybox" rel="' + this + '" href="' + name + '/' + i +'.jpg"><img class="img" src="' + name + '/' + i + '.jpg" /></a>');
              }
            }
          });
        });
      });
    }
  });
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

It creates each DIV that's needed, but instead of putting each in their own they stack

birthday contains "birthday, camping, july fourth"

camping contains "camping, july fourth"

july fourth contains itself

How do I go about making it not contain each category after it?

Comment: if u are use same JSON file  then your each loop not correct.
because there  r no need to use two Each loop.
you can do with one each loop.

Comment: I've tried removing
    $.each(response, function() {
and changing the next one to 
    $.each(response, function(name, photos) {
and no images load at all

Comment: please post same JOSN file which u  are using in your code
"events.json "

Comment: I already have, the one in the post is the one I am using

Comment: @TesoMayn The JSON array that you're showing us is very vague. What do the numbers mean? Show us how the `response` variable looks. Where do the `name` and `photos` variables come from?

Comment: They come from the JSON... I've posted 100% of the code, besides the HTML for styling, the name and photo variables come from the JSON when it's parsed, name = birthday, camping, july fourth; and number = the number that follows them, the response variable is set from the .ajax, it's the content of the JSON after being loaded

Comment: @TesoMayn I understand what you mean now. But that is the worst JSON response I've ever seen. Very badly formatted and that's what makes it so difficult to write a clean solution to your problem. Something like `[ { "galleryName": "Birthday", "numPhotos": "10" }, etc ]` would be much more logical but I assume you can't control that.

Comment: Totally agree with
@Alternatex

Comment: @TesoMayn I've come up with a disgusting solution. I'll submit it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually figured out how to fix this, it was quite simple and a total derp on my end

I just changed the $('.gallery').append()s to $(this).append()

Also, I know the JSON wasn't great, I have fixed that.

```
$.getJSON("events.json", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(index, d) {
    var name = d.name;
    var photos = d.count;
    $('#container').append('<div class="gallery" name="' + name + '"></div>');
    $('div[name="'+name+'"]').append(function() {
      for ( var i = 1; i <= photos; i++) {
        if (i < 10) {
          $(this).append('<a class="fancybox" rel="' + this + '" href="' + name + '/0' + i + '.jpg"><img class="img" src="' + name + '/0' + i + '.jpg" /></a>');
        } else {
          $(this).append('<a class="fancybox" rel="' + this + '" href="' + name + '/' + i +'.jpg"><img class="img" src="' + name + '/' + i + '.jpg" /></a>');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh damn, well yours is better than mine! Set it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I can't for two days :<

Comment: Haha yes it took me a while since I'm at work. Accept your answer so people don't come looking for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.. Hopefully it's not too convoluted..

```
// Kind of necessary in the way my solution works
function getPropertyName(prop, value) {
    for (var i in prop) {
        if (prop[i] == value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'events.json',
        success: function(response) {
            $.each(response, function( index, gallery ) {
                // gallery[Object.keys(gallery)[0]] gets the first property of the gallery object
                var galleryName = getPropertyName(gallery, gallery[Object.keys(gallery)[0]]);
                var numPhotos = parseInt(gallery[galleryName]);

                // I used 'data-name' instead of 'name' as the attribute to keep it more in line with the HTML standard
                $('#container').append('<div class="gallery" data-name="' + galleryName + '"></div>');

                for (var i = 1; i <= numPhotos; i++) {
                    $('div[data-name="' + galleryName + '"').append(function() {
                        if (i < 10) {
                            $(this).append('<a class="fancybox" href="' + galleryName + '/0' + i + '.jpg"><img class="img" src="' + galleryName + '/0' + i + '.jpg" /></a>');
                        } else {
                            $(this).append('<a class="fancybox" href="' + galleryName + '/' + i +'.jpg"><img class="img" src="' + galleryName + '/' + i + '.jpg" /></a>');
                        }
                    });
                };
            });
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();
        }
    });
});
```